# Change the button type for a Bootstrap 3 button-group

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on a project that requires being able to set a schedule with the days of the week that a given task occurs. What I've come up with seems to be functional enough (fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tkturney/y7z9vgx0/3/)):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <h6><b>Weekly:</b></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{'active': currentSchedule.monday}">
          <input ng-model="currentSchedule.monday" type="checkbox" checked="{{currentSchedule.monday}}"> Monday
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{'active': currentSchedule.tuesday}">
          <input ng-model="currentSchedule.tuesday" type="checkbox" checked="{{currentSchedule.tuesday}}"> Tuesday
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{'active': currentSchedule.wednesday}">
          <input ng-model="currentSchedule.wednesday" type="checkbox" checked="{{currentSchedule.wednesday}}"> Wednesday
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{'active': currentSchedule.thursday}">
          <input ng-model="currentSchedule.thursday" type="checkbox" checked="{{currentSchedule.thursday}}"> Thursday
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{'active': currentSchedule.friday}">
          <input ng-model="currentSchedule.friday" type="checkbox" checked="{{currentSchedule.friday}}"> Friday
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{'active': currentSchedule.saturday}">
          <input ng-model="currentSchedule.saturday" type="checkbox" checked="{{currentSchedule.saturday}}"> Saturday
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info" ng-class="{'active': currentSchedule.sunday}">
          <input ng-model="currentSchedule.sunday" type="checkbox" checked="{{currentSchedule.sunday}}"> Sunday
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('testApp', []).controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentSchedule = {
    monday: true,
    tuesday: true,
    wednesday: true,
    thursday: true,
    friday: false,
    saturday: false,
    sunday: true
  };
}])
```

CSS:

```
.btn-info.active {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

However, my client has seen the nifty little toggle buttons that have either a red or green line on the side, depending on whether it's active.

If I weren't looking for it, I could find numerous examples of the button that he's looking for, but, right now, I'm not having any luck.

Does anyone know if these are available through a plug-in, or something like that?

Comment: You could use [Bootstrap Switch] (http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) To get the look/color you would just need to adjust the CSS.

Comment: @DottedT I looked at that, and it's a nice light-switch implementation, but I'm looking for something more along the lines of a "power button" - click the button and the little stripe on the side turns green, click it again, and the stripe turns red.

Comment: Here's a different [example] (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ButtonSwitches/index4.html) This one is created through just CSS so you could just take the example and style it any way you like.

Comment: @DottedT Thanks - that worked [beautifully!](https://jsfiddle.net/tkturney/1wgL643s/1/) If you want to put it out there as an answer, I'll mark it as such...